# How can we determine the current region with AWS Fargate

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I have a Java application running on AWS Fargate. Regions.getCurrentRegion() returns null from within an AWS Fargate for security reasons

Is there an alternative way to determine which region the fargate container is running in?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Fargate, the current region is available via the `AWS_REGION` environment variable.

Comment: Do you also know how to get the AZ for this case ?

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: If it's not documented it's subject to change

Comment: Here is where it is documented: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/ECS_CLI_Configuration.html

Comment: @GunWanderer That's documentation for the ECS CLI; it doesn't have anything to do with the ECS/Fargate runtime environment...

Comment: @JesseFriedman, you didn’t read the entire page. Look at the bottom of the page, #3: Environment variables

Comment: @GunWanderer I did read the page, and I stand by my statement... The page says that the ECS CLI, a local command-line tool, configures its region using several methods, including looking at the `AWS_REGION` environment variable. The AWS CLI and SDKs also look at this variable, making it something of a convention - but the description of a command-line tool's behavior is in _no way whatsoever_ documentation of what environment variables may or may not be set in the runtime environment of an ECS task. The page makes no mention at all of ECS runtime behavior.

Comment: @JesseFriedman, interesting interpretation. I’m not going to try to convince you to do what you don’t want. To each their own.

#3. Environment variables - Attempts to fetch the region from the following environment variables:
AWS_REGION
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

Comment: The answerer Samuel Karp used to work at Amazon on containers, so I think he's a reliable source. There's two separate things here: Fargate environment variables and configuring ECS CLI. They both happen to use AWS_REGION, though Fargate doesn't seem to be documented.

Comment: The way I read the above comments, nobody says that they've tried accessing the env var AWS_REGION from an ECS task to see what they get.  I can confirm that ECS does indeed set this variable.  I have a Java app running as an ECS task, and the Java code `System.getenv("AWS_REGION")`returns the region that my task is running in, "us-east-2" for the test i just ran.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AWS java sdk you can chain  [`AwsRegionProvider`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/regions/AwsRegionProvider.html) and abstract out logic around region retrieval. If you use a credentials profile, or the environment variable changes, or it eventually becomes available in [TaskMetadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html) you can chain region providers so that you can  get region wherever it's available. This also allows you to reuse code that may run on different types of AWS infrastructure.

You would construct an [`AwsRegionProviderChain`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/regions/AwsRegionProviderChain.html) and pass in an instance of each relevant `AwsRegionProvider` such as `AwsEnvVarOverrideRegionProvider`, `AwsProfileRegionProvider` etc.

Comment: I like this answer, but is there a way to configure the timeout for all providers? Doing this seems to increase my application startup time by quite a lot

Comment: you could try using a CompletableFuture.allOf to get the first one that returns. If speed is imperative you may be better off doing something platform specific