# C# AWS - How to determine AWS Region Endpoint dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, aws-regions

I am connecting to AWS SecretManager, in which my code connects to specific region endpoint(below code)

> *AmazonSecretsManagerConfig config = new AmazonSecretsManagerConfig { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1 };*

Now, I want to add one more new region *RegionEndpoint.USEast2*

I want this RegionEndpoint selection dynamically, based on the specific region request. Kindly help, How can I configure Multi Region in my C# Code?

Note: My app is running on Fargate and not on EC2 instance, so below solutions won't work:

> *client = Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.Region.SystemName;*

or

> *client = new Amazon&&&&Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-east-1"));*

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the current region from reading the `AWS_REGION` environment variable as mentioned in this post: [How can we determine the current region with AWS Fargate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886219/how-can-we-determine-the-current-region-with-aws-fargate/51886404).

Comment: The comments on that post indicate this is an undocumented feature and thus subject to change.